# How to load module include files in .test file?

Tags: 7, testing

I'm trying to update the Drupal 7 version of the password_policy.test file that is included with the [Password Policy module](http://drupal.org/project/password_policy). When I run the tests, I'm getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_policy_constraint_uppercase_validate()".

The function in question is in an include file in the constraints subdirectory, located inside the module's directory. I've tried adding to the test's setUp() function, along the lines of:

```
drupal_load('module', 'password_policy');
module_load_include('inc', 'password_policy', 'constraint_uppercase');
```

I've also tried adding the module_load_include line inside the individual test method generating the error. However, none of my attempts so far appear to be working and the error still persists.

How should I go about loading the ./constraints/constraint_uppercase.inc and other include files, so that the necessary functions are loaded prior to the tests being run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a flaw in your code, `module_load_include` works by including files relative to the module base dir, so you should do

```
module_load_include('inc', 'password_policy', 'constraints /constraint_uppercase');
```

to include `password_policy/constraints/constraint_uppercase.inc`

When you do

```
module_load_include('inc', 'password_policy', 'constraint_uppercase');
```

You instead try to include `password_policy/constraint_uppercase.inc` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can add in the modules .info file:

```
files[] = constraints/includeme.inc
files[] = constraints/includeme2.inc
files[] = tests/included.test
```

Comment: Files added in the info file on serve the purpose of building the class registry, which allows Drupal to auto load files which contain the needed definition of a PHP class. That's why you should add the test file in the info file, as tests are classes, but this won't solve the problem of loading a class in the test itself.